# Storing binary files on the cloud with direct-download links

Tags: web-apps, web, web-services, cloud-service, cloud-storage

I'm looking for a web app which I can use to store some binary files of around `20MB` each.  They are around maybe `200MB` in total size. There should be a *direct-download* link. Since I'm going to have to download the binary files from within some unit tests.

Some repositories have been using such platforms to store files with *direct-download* link:

https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.70.0/source/boost_1_70_0.tar.gz

I researched but I couldn't find a free storage service with *direct-download* link feature. Does anybody know such a service?

Comment: As we recommend software, and not hosting services or service providers (see e.g. [Are questions for service providers welcome at our site?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/185) and [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)) I assume you're looking for a software to self-host. What you describe should e.g. be possible with Nextcloud. Several providers even offer to run that for you ([incomplete list here](https://github.com/nextcloud/providers)).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for your help. I tried a Nextcloud provider, but I had problems with *direct-download* for some reason. I'm not sure, maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I've never investigated that – I just know one can share direct links. Those few I got in the past indeed required opening the webpage and clicking another link, which I always found strange but never investigated (maybe using that second link to start with would work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used Google Drive with its direct download parameters:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YourFileID`

Google Drive file ID is inside the *shareable link* when you share a file publicly. E.g. file ID would be something like `1lWCDMGcu2kCRZZMAnl1lJMB_QNirWUcl`.

This helped:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/is-there-a-direct-download-links-for-files-on-google-drive#comment118188_34001